# How to reorder matrix to its canonical form (Markov chain)?

Tags: statistics, markov-chains, markov-process

Is it possible to rearrange this matrix in its canonical form (link below)? I have searched numerous websites and videos and have only found answers for small matrices where you automatically get the identity matrix just by rearranging the rows. How can I do that here if the absorbing states are all even states?

The matrix I have is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1/6 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 1/6 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The canonical form is the block matrix form
$$
   P = \left[\!\begin{array}{c|c}Q & R \\ \hline 0 & I\end{array}\!\right]
$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I added an image (well, a link, couldn't embed the image) to show what I need. I need to calculate the probability of each of the terminal (absorbing) states so I need to rearrange it to its canonical way.

Comment: You don't actually need to do any calculations to see that each of the five absorbing states has probability $1/5$; that's clear from the symmetry of the problem.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I thought the same, but that's not the answer: it's 2/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6.

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot to worry about the starting distribution. If you start in state $1$, then you have a $1/6$ chance of going to the corresponding absorbing state right way (which is why the first absorbing state has an extra $1/6$ probability). The other $5/6$ of the time, you go to a random non-absorbing state, and from there the problem is symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to make sense, you have to understand what you're doing when you're rearranging the rows and columns of the matrix, and why you're allowed to do it without getting a completely unrelated transition matrix.

The $(i,j)$ entry of a transition matrix tells you the probability of going from the $i^{\text{th}}$ state to the $j^{\text{th}}$ state. But deciding which state is the $1^{\text{st}}$ state, which is the $2^{\text{nd}}$ state, and so on - that's often arbitrary. So if you number the states of a Markov chain, you get a transition matrix; if you number them differently, you get a different transition matrix.

The canonical form of the transition matrix is simply the one where **all absorbing states get numbered last**. So how do we get there from here? We renumber the states. However, the number of a state tells us two things: which row it corresponds to, and which column. As a consequence, **we are allowed to reorder the rows however we like, provided we reorder the columns in the same way**.

In your case, you've identified the even-numbered states as the absorbing states. So the rearrangement you should apply is:

1. First, reorder the rows: put rows $1, 3, 5, 7, 9$ first, and rows $2, 4, 6, 8, 10$ after them.
2. Second, reorder the columns in the same way: put columns $1, 3, 5, 7, 9$ (of the matrix you got after step 1) first, and columns $2, 4, 6, 8, 10$ after them.